# Android Studio - Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm facing a problem whenever I try to run an existing flutter project, everything is updated I don't know how to fix this, thanks in advance !

error image

[image: 1]

Comment: lot of methods are not defined like walletScreen().

Comment: Oh can you tell me how to fix it please? As I said I'm a beginner so I'm a bit confused, thanks !

Comment: You needed to create all the methods which are undefined in that particular class.

Answer (score 1):

**

> I think wrong with your pubspec.yaml file

**
Got to terminal and write flutter pub get